# I saw a symbol (double vertical line) on Labview 8.0. Is it "or" function?

Tags: labview

I saw a symbol, what there is vertical double line inside triangle shape, on Labview 8.0.

Is it "or" function?

[image: Image of Labview symbol]

I also asked in Labview Community.

Comment: bahadir3301 - I see you have deleted your comment explaining the solution which you found for yourself. Therefore I have removed the comments regarding turning that into an answer as it seems you don't want to do that, and another site member has now answered the question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the absolute value function.

[image]